# What type of brace should I use for the jumpers knee injury (patellar tendinopathy)?

Tags: injury, grappling, kickboxing, mixed-martial-arts

Due to intensive training in the past few weeks, I injured my knee with the jumpers knee condition. For the first few weeks I have to rest and do nothing but after that I would like to start training again (which includes kicking and grappling).

What kind of knee band/brace should I opt for so I have optimal protection without much limitation?

Comment: Did your doctor recommend a knee brace? This comes very close to medical recommendation.

Comment: Yes, my physiotherapist said I could go for a knee band or a knee brace specially made for the jumpers knee. He didn't actuallly recommended one in specific. I can find both on the market but I wondered which suits best for fighting sports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the physiotherapist, I went for the PSB Patella knee strap and it feels like the right choice. It keeps my kneecap (patella) in place and it makes sure I will not get full tension on my without feeling restrictive at all and it wasn't that expensive.